# sbt-idea 1.2.0 unresolved for SBT 0.12.0 and Scala 2.10.0?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-idea

I am creating a new SBT project and here are the contents of my SBT files:

**build.properties**

```
sbt.version=0.12.0
```

**plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.2.0")
```

**build.sbt**

```
name := "peroo"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.10.0"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  Classpaths.typesafeResolver,
  "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/",
  "Sonatype releases"  at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  compilerPlugin("org.scala-lang.plugins" % "continuations" % "2.10.0"),
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "13.0"
)

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-P:continuations:enable", "-deprecation", "-unchecked", "-feature")

autoCompilerPlugins := true
```

Here's the error I get when I attempt to start `sbt` in the project directory root:

```
➜  peroo  sbt 
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/rahulphulore/projects/rahul/peroo/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/rahulphulore/projects/rahul/peroo/project/}default-941135...
[info] Resolving com.google.guava#guava;13.0 ...
[info] Resolving com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.2.0 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.2.0
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.github.mpeltonen/sbt-idea/scala_2.10/sbt_0.12/1.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.github.mpeltonen/sbt-idea/scala_2.10/sbt_0.12/1.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/rahulphulore/.ivy2/local/com.github.mpeltonen/sbt-idea/scala_2.10/sbt_0.12/1.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.github.mpeltonen/sbt-idea/scala_2.10/sbt_0.12/1.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Sonatype snapshots: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/mpeltonen/sbt-idea_2.10_0.12/1.2.0/sbt-idea-1.2.0.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype releases: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/github/mpeltonen/sbt-idea_2.10_0.12/1.2.0/sbt-idea-1.2.0.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/mpeltonen/sbt-idea_2.10_0.12/1.2.0/sbt-idea-1.2.0.pom
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#main;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#actions;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#classpath;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#launcher-interface;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#interface;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#io;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#control;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#completion;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#collections;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;1.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#api;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compiler-integration;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#logging;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#process;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compile;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#persist;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbinary#sbinary_2.9.0;0.4.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#classfile;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compiler-ivy-integration;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#ivy;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-rc1 ...
[info] Resolving com.jcraft#jsch;0.1.46 ...
[info] Resolving commons-httpclient#commons-httpclient;3.1 ...
[info] Resolving commons-logging#commons-logging;1.0.4 ...
[info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#run;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#task-system;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#tasks;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#tracking;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#cache;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#testing;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-agent;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.testing#test-interface;0.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#command;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_8_2;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_10_0-m4;0.12.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.plugins#continuations;2.10.0 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.2.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.github.mpeltonen:sbt-idea:1.2.0 (sbtVersion=0.12, scalaVersion=2.10)
[warn] 
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.2.0: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:211)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:114)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:114)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:102)
    at sbt.IvySbt.liftedTree1$1(Ivy.scala:49)
    at sbt.IvySbt.action$1(Ivy.scala:49)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:75)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:79)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.liftedTree1$1(Locks.scala:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:30)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:27)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:58)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:99)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:95)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:114)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:121)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:949)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:947)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$54.apply(Defaults.scala:970)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$54.apply(Defaults.scala:968)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:972)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:967)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:975)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$45.apply(Defaults.scala:855)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$45.apply(Defaults.scala:852)
    at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf10$1.apply(Structure.scala:586)
    at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf10$1.apply(Structure.scala:586)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
    at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
    at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$5.work(System.scala:71)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:238)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.2.0: not found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
➜  peroo
```

What could be the issue?

**Edit:**

Here's what my project directory structure looks like:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the files you showed are in their proper respective directories? `build.properties` and `plugins.sbt` should be in the `project/` subdirectory of your project's base directory and `build.sbt` should be in that base directory. If you have those correct, you can try to eradicate your `~/.ivy2` and `project/target` directories entirely (and live with "(re-)downloading the Internet" the next time you run SBT).

Answer (score 2):

I added it on Mac Mountain Lion in `~/.sbt/plugins/plugins.sbt`. It works and dependencies no longer fail. I think you will need to use it outside of scala version and add the s`cala-reflect.jar` to your path manually inside the IDE to get this working.

Comment: Comment on edit: Still spits the same error. I am using OS X Mountain Lion.

Comment: I tried many variations but nothing is helping. Here is the source - https://bitbucket.org/missingfaktor/peroo/src.

Comment: Uh-oh. My bad. The `plugins.sbt` seems to being ignored. :( `gen-idea` and `idea` commands are not working.

Comment: Could you please take a look at my repo and see what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your `plugins.sbt` file must either be global, as @alex23 illustrates, or in the project's `project/` subdirectory. This way it applies to SBT and not to your own code, which presumably has no need for it.

Comment: Here's what my project directory structure looks like - http://i.imgur.com/bKPvnIu.png. Do you see any problems in it?

Comment: I tried many variations but nothing is helping. Here is the source - https://bitbucket.org/missingfaktor/peroo/src.

Comment: You need to `rm plugins.sbt` (since you have it in `project/` as well already). I'll add my stock recommendation that you use Paul Phillips' (PaulP) SBT launcher (https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras) and put all non-project plugins.sbt in `~/.sbt/<sbtVersion>/plugins/plugins.sbt`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the project releases page](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea/releases) the most recent version of sbt-idea is 1.5.1 that was released for sbt `0.11`, `0.12` and `0.13`.

There is however a more recent version of the plugin available in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/mpeltonen/ - `1.5.2`.

You should be able to use the plugin with the following line in `project/sbt-idea.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.5.2")
```

There's [a much easier yet slower approach](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html#revision) to specify a proper version number - use `latest.integration` for the version part.

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "latest.integration")
```

An excerpt about `latest.integration`'s performance from [the documentation of Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html#revision):

> Note that in order to find the latest revision with the appropriate status Ivy has to parse all the ivy files in your repository from the last one until it finds such a revision. Hence don't be surprised if the resolution slow down.

Please note that both IntelliJ IDEA and sbt improved since you asked the question, and there's less need for the plugin currently as in IDEA ["The new version of Scala plugin comes with built-in support for SBT, with code completion and dependencies import."](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced apparently the same problem but with a newer version (1.5.X) that I "fixed" simply downgrading to the version 1.4.0 of the gen-idea plugin.

```
cat ~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.4.0")
```