# Not specifying version in addSbtPlugin possible?

Tags: sbt

If I want to include a plugin for sbt I use `addSbtPlugin()` in `plugins.sbt`. So to add the gen-idea plugin I would use the following line:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.5.0")
```

Alas, I've to explicitly specify the version `1.5.0`. What if I want to use the latest available version when it becomes available?

When I omit the third parameter I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\JDearing\Documents\deleteme\LearningScala>sbt gen-idea
C:\Users\JDearing\.sbt\0.13\plugins\build.sbt:1: error: type mismatch;
 found   : sbt.impl.GroupArtifactID
 required: sbt.ModuleID
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" )
                                ^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

Is it possible to avoid specifying the version in `addSbtPlugin()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** No. There's no way to leave the version off. It's part of `sbt.ModuleID`.

You can however use `latest.integration` or `latest.milestone` to avoid specifying the version explicitly. Ivy and hence SBT will take care of ["selecting the latest version being either a milestone or a release"](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html#revision).

You may also consult [my answer to a similar question about the sbt-idea plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20826378/1305344).

Answer (score 3):

sbt plugin is just another library for your build
https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala#L1513

And for a library you have Ivy resolution rules

> Ivy revisions
>   The revision in groupID % artifactID % revision does
>   not have to be a single fixed version. Ivy can select the latest
>   revision of a module according to constraints you specify. Instead of
>   a fixed revision like "1.6.1", you specify "latest.integration",
>   "2.9.+", or "[1.0,)". See the [Ivy revisions](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.3.0-rc1/ivyfile/dependency.html#revision) documentation for details.

from 
http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html#ivy-revisions