# How to Point Intellij at SBT Libraries for Scala Project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm trying to use this example: https://github.com/spray/spray-template for a Spray project, however I can't figure out how to point Intellij at the dependencies downloaded via SBT.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're using IntelliJ version 13, you need only the Scala plug-in (which has built-in SBT support); just open the project by selecting the `build.sbt` file.

Comment: @Jesper seems to be a legit answer, just like two already existing (why don't you write it so?)

Comment: Might be of help http://stackoverflow.com/q/14979361/1305344

Answer (score 4):

If you're using IntelliJ version 13, you need only the Scala plug-in (which has built-in SBT support); just open the project by selecting the `build.sbt` file.

Comment: I have had no luck with the built in sbt support so far: the gen-idea was the only way.  I will try again though with the latest IJ version ( presently 13.1.2).

Answer (score 1):

Use this SBT plugin to generate Intellij IDEA project files: https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea

Answer (score 1):

Add SBT plugin for creating IntelliJ IDEA projects in your ~/.sbt/0.xx/plugins/build.sbt or PROJECT_DIR/project/plugins.sbt. Use `gen-idea` command to create an IntelliJ project and `open the project` in IntelliJ. That should be it.

Comment: And run gen-idea every time you add stuff to your dependencies so they show up in the IDE.

Comment: wow that's inconvenient. i have many things to remember already, that is asking likely too much.